# R: Plotting RANEFs in Mixed Model Effect

Tags: r, plot, lme4, mixed-models

So I'm fairly new to R. I'm working on a project with a data set the looks at the Age of birds. We have >400,000 observations from 95 individuals. I task is to this:

"This graph would be more convincing if it had some data points on it alongside the lines. You can get the datapoints from ranef within getcall in lme4. So, run the model without an age and age2 term. Then, pull out the random effect terms (the values for each individual), then plot them (y = random effect, x = age)."

This is the graph in question (it was made in Excel using our model): [Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PXfnv.png)

So I ran this

```
> lmbdna<-lmer(Gs ~ (1 | Individual) + Bin + year + Mass)
> ranef(lmbdna)
>$Individual

> plot(Age, ranef(lmbdna))
```

And I got this

> Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
>     'x' and 'y' lengths differ

I am really lost and I'm not how about graphing the ranefs to the age. Is there a way to associate an age to an individuals to get rid of that error?

Here is some of my data:

```
Indiv   Age Mass   MaxDepth Depth       Gs       PDBA  Bin year
69903   12  1015    3.806   3.025   0.1854302   92.7151 A   N
52712   20  957.5   3.806   3.025   0.204678    102.339 A   T
55969   19  1002.5  3.806   3.025   0.222338    111.169 A   T
64442   15  1040    3.806   3.025   0.1872954   93.6477 A   T
76252   11  940     3.806   3.025   0.223136    111.568 A   T
53391   21  1022.5  3.806   3.025   0.234452    117.226 A   E
53391   21  1022.5  3.806   3.025   0.299438    149.719 A   E
60117   18  937.5   3.806   3.025   0.1469442   73.4721 A   E
60151   18  970     3.806   3.025   0.1941052   97.0526 A   E
52712   20  957.5   3.855   3.025   0.1812926   90.6463 A   T
52712   20  957.5   3.855   3.025   0.25101     125.505 A   T
64442   15  1040    3.855   3.025   0.1850976   92.5488 A   T
64442   15  1040    3.855   3.025   0.1026478   51.3239 A   T
76252   11  940     3.855   3.025   0.235822    117.911 A   T
78712   10  880     3.855   3.025   0.1638106   81.9053 A   T
87819   7   1000    3.855   3.025   0.166391    83.1955 A   T
90281   6   957.5   3.855   3.025   0.1493948   74.6974 A   T
60151   18  970     3.855   3.025   0.1904232   95.2116 A   E
69944   12  915     3.904   3.025   0.256504    128.252 A   N
3260    24  960     3.904   3.025   0.168019    84.0095 A   T
52712   20  957.5   3.904   3.025   0.270704    135.352 A   T
64442   15  1040    3.904   3.025   0.1507102   75.3551 A   T
71432   12  970     3.904   3.025   0.1238154   61.9077 A   T
80538   15  917.5   3.904   3.025   0.236976    118.488 A   E
76583   14  870     3.952   3.025   0.295982    147.991 A   N
84420   7   1005    3.952   3.025   0.1861876   93.0938 A   N
87819   7   1000    3.952   3.025   0.178179    89.0895 A   T
53391   21  1022.5  3.952   3.025   0.1917954   95.8977 A   E
53391   21  1022.5  3.952   3.025   0.1482036   74.1018 A   E
53391   21  1022.5  3.952   3.025   0.1999868   99.9934 A   E
53391   21  1022.5  3.952   3.025   0.276334    138.167 A   E
60151   18  970     3.952   3.025   0.1776108   88.8054 A   E
80538   15  917.5   3.952   3.025   0.188733    94.3665 A   E
69944   12  915     4.001   3.025   0.2596      129.8   A   N
3260    24  960     4.001   3.025   0.1824546   91.2273 A   T
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide a minimum reproducible example?

Comment: You're treating `ranef(lmbdna)` as if it's just a vector. Assign it to a variable and extract for plotting exactly the parts you want. `my_ranef = ranef(lmbdna)`. Use `str(my_ranef)` to see what's there. Your probably want to plot something like `my_ranef$Individual`, but make sure the orderings and all are correct.

Comment: @NBATrends: I added the first few lines from my data into the description, does that help at all? Thanks for the reply!

Comment: @Gregor: I'm not too sure what you mean, could you elaborate. I'm sorry, but I'm still not very advanced in R. Thanks

Comment: @NBATrends, Your answer that seemed to have been deleted, also helped me with solving this issue. Thanks!

Comment: @LearningTheMacros no worries, glad it helped. Deleted it because I wasn't sure I answered your question especially as I am plotting max(age) against the individual's random effect. I will undelete it though, in case somebody else benefits in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is that the random effects you extracted are per individual, while the age data you are trying to plot against is for each observation. You will need to aggregate that to the individual level (e.g. take the max for each individual across all their observations to get the result you are looking for. The example below uses the text you supplied above.

Not exactly sure if this is what you are after, but the main issue is that your vectors are of different lengths. Hopefully, the code below will give you some ideas. Would have been great to get a larger sample of data.

```
require(lme4)

# the data snapshot supplied above only contains one level of the factor bin, let's add another
dta[dta$Indiv < 7000, "Bin"] <- "B"

# estimate model
lmbdna <- lmer(Gs ~ (1 | Indiv) + Bin + year + Mass, dta)

# random effects are for indivuals, so need to aggregate individuals' ages
plt_dta <- aggregate(dta$Age, by = list(dta$Indiv), max)

# create one dataset by merging with random effects
plt_dta <- merge(plt_dta, ranef(lmbdna)$Indiv, by.x = 1, by.y = 0)

# plot data
plot(plt_dta[,2], plt_dta[,3], xlab = "age", ylab = "ranef")
```

Comment: There is no variation in age in the extract you gave above.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think we can get a meaningful model based on the data you shared, so let's use something like the example in `?ranef`:

```
library("lme4")
fm1 = lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (1 | Subject), data = sleepstudy)

my_ranef = ranef(fm1)
str(my_ranef)
# List of 1
#  $ Subject:'data.frame':  18 obs. of  1 variable:
#   ..$ (Intercept): num [1:18] 40.78 -77.85 -63.11 4.41 10.22 ...
#  - attr(*, "class")= chr "ranef.mer"
```

`str()` is useful for viewing the structure of an object. Here we can see that `my_ranef` is a list of 1 item, and that item is a data frame (named `Subject`) with 18 rows and 1 column (named `(Intercept)`). Let's look closely at the data frame:

```
head(my_ranef$Subject)
#     (Intercept)
# 308   40.783710
# 309  -77.849554
# 310  -63.108567
# 330    4.406442
# 331   10.216189
# 332    8.221238
```

So the data frame has row names that correspond to each individual subject, and then the random effect intercept is in the (Intercept) column. So we can plot the random effects like this:

```
plot(row.names(my_ranef$Subject), my_ranef$Subject[, "(Intercept)"])
```

The problem you had is that you were giving either the whole list or a data frame as the `y` argument to your plot, whereas you need to extract just the vector.

We could also extract the random effects

```
est_ranef = my_ranef$Subject[, "(Intercept)"]
```

(note that the parentheses make `"(Intercept)"` a non-standard column name which adds a little difficulty in extracting it, a simple `$` wouldn't work *a la* `my_ranef$Subject$(Intercept)`, but we can use `[` and a quoted column name as above, or backticks can be used with `$` like this:

```
my_ranef$Subject$`(Intercept)`
```

If you look at `ranef()` for a more complicated model, you'll see *why* the list of data frames structure is used.

Comment: Hi Gregor,

Thanks for the help, this along with @NBATrends answer (that seemed to have been deleted, helped me solve the issue.

Thanks